# AngularJS2.0 Tile Homepage Animation To New Page

Tags: animation, angular, routes

I am starting on a new website project using AngularJS 2.0.

However, I have a particular idea which I have no idea how to work out.

The website would work as follows: (I have put a link down here with multiple images that I hope can illustrate my idea).

1. Homepage with 20 rectangles, all having a different background color and some text and maybe a picture inside of it.
2. When clicking on one of the rectangles, the background of that tile will animate to a new page. The color of the header of that "new" page would be the color of the background of the tile. I think this should be done using the routing module right?

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5IVo.jpg)

How can I achieve this? Should I be using like 20 different components on the home screen which I somehow animate to a new page using routing or should I do something else?

I am kinda new to AngularJS but I'd love to learn more, would be great if anyone could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance